# How to set displayName when registering a SIP account in c#

Tags: c#, sip, freeswitch

I try to register a SIP account. The registration is successful (to freeswitch). However, I would love to add a display name of the account. How do I do that? The documentation of Freeswitch is unclear about this. I have tried it this way:

```
 AccountConfig acfg = new AccountConfig();
            acfg.idUri = "sip:" + Account + "@" + Domain;
            pjsua2.SipHeader header = new pjsua2.SipHeader();
            header.hName = "displayName";
            header.hValue = "Dit is de persoon die als account: " + Account;
            acfg.regConfig.headers.Add(header);
```

But this is unsuccessful. I am pretty sure I have to add the display name by adding a header but I think I use the wrong one.
I do not receive an error using the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [RFC3261](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-20.39):

> The following are examples of valid To header fields:
>
> ```
>  To: The Operator <sip:operator@cs.columbia.edu>;tag=287447
>  t: sip:+12125551212@server.phone2net.com
> ```

So you've to embed your SIP-URI into `<` and `>` and put your display name in front of it. Since to- and from-URI have to be the same when doing a SIP REGISTER you also have to set the from-URI. So you should change your code to:

```
        AccountConfig acfg = new AccountConfig();
        acfg.idUri = $"{YourDisplayNameHere} <sip: {Account}@{Domain}>";
        ...
```

Since I'm not familiar with PJSIP you need to check if you've to set to-/from-URI for the SIP REGISTER in an additional way.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you sir! This indeed is the method to add the display name. I've added it into my application.

Comment: @Moerwald. can you ping me. my skype id is  prince tomy. Can you just put the registration and outbound call codes in pjsip using c#.